# PHP making navigation from XML attributes

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to make a navigation made from XML database attributes. Some of the elements have the same attribute value, but when I try to echo that value only once it doesn't work. I've tried array_key_exist, in_array and array_search and not a single one works. Right now I have 2 Samsung attributes and 2 Iphone attribues. Samsung shows up 2 times, but Iphone shows only once. Can you help me out?
PHP :

```
<?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("Database/products.xml");
        $stack = array();
        foreach($xml->Mobile as $phone){
            $attr_value = $phone[0]['model'];
            $attr = (string)$attr_value;
            $link = "ponuda.php?name=".$attr;
            $array_check = array_search($attr, $stack);
            if (!($array_check)) {
                $stack[] = $attr;
                echo '<li><a href=' . $link . '>' . $attr . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

XML :

```
<Products>
    <Mobile model="Samsung">
        <Model>Samsung Galaxy A5</Model>
        <Price>150</Price>
        <Description></Description>
        <Picture></Picture>
        <Screen></Screen>
        <Memory></Memory>
        <Android></Android>
    </Mobile>
    <Mobile model="Samsung">
        <Model>Samsung Galaxy A3</Model>
        <Price>130</Price>
        <Description></Description>
        <Picture></Picture>
        <Screen></Screen>
        <Memory></Memory>
        <Android></Android>
    </Mobile>
<Mobile model="Iphone">
        <Model>Iphone 8</Model>
        <Price>500</Price>
        <Description></Description>
        <Picture></Picture>
        <Screen></Screen>
        <Memory></Memory>
        <Android></Android>
    </Mobile>
    <Mobile model="Iphone">
        <Model>Iphone 8+</Model>
        <Price>450</Price>
        <Description></Description>
        <Picture></Picture>
        <Screen></Screen>
        <Memory></Memory>
        <Android></Android>
    </Mobile>
</Products>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `in_array` this way?

```
<?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("Database/products.xml");
        $stack = array();
        foreach($xml->Mobile as $phone){
            $attr_value = $phone[0]['model'];
            $attr = trim($attr_value);
            $link = "ponuda.php?name=".$attr;
            $array_check = in_array($attr, $stack);
            if (!$array_check) {
                $stack[] = $attr;
                echo '<li><a href=' . $link . '>' . $attr . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
```

Difference is in two lines `$attr = trim($attr_value);` and `$array_check = in_array($attr, $stack);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use  [**array_unique**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$stack = array();
foreach($xml->Mobile as $phone){
    $stack [] = $phone[0]['model'];  
}

echo '<pre>'.   print_r(array_unique($stack),true).'</pre>';
```

result

```
    (
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Samsung
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Iphone
        )

)
```